# CSS3 space-around form button not adding space

Tags: html, css

If this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Google</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav id="you">
        <a href="#">Gmail</a>
        <a href="#">Apps</a>
        <a href="#">You</a>
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
    </nav>
    <form>
        <img src="static/Google-logo-520x245.jpg" width="250" height="125" alt="Google  Logo">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="search">
        <button id="left" name="Google">Google Search</button>
        <button id="right" name="Feeling">Feeling Lucky</button>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Then why doesn't the  justify-content: space-around option put space  between my 2 buttons instead they overlay.

I am trying to  keep the  image, input field and buttons all aligned to the  center vertically and each on their  own row horizontally.

my css

```
#you {
    position: fixed;
    right: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#you a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

input {
    width: 400px;
    /*display: block; */

    position: fixed;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    height: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

form {
    position: fixed;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/ */
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 135%;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i [rewrote](http://jsfiddle.net/8872w2pc/) your css.

```
form{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
img{
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}
input{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Please take notice of the centering techniques i have used:

- **text-align: center** - Highly effective for inline displayed elements.
- **fixed width + margin: 0 auto** - Effective when you have a block element.

Comment: if you add #you a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
} to push the links to the right then it upsets the whole apple cart pushing the links halfway down the page https://jsfiddle.net/8872w2pc/

Comment: hei @sayth, here is an updated verion of the fiddle. By floating the content on the right you'll get the desired effect but you'll need another DIV with the css property clear set to both (see in fiddle). If this html thing is for the long run i higly reccomand you reading a book about it :)  https://jsfiddle.net/8872w2pc/4/

Answer (score 1):

You should add display:flex property to the parent, and justify-content: space-around; property too for getting space around its children.

```
form {
position: fixed;
top: 45%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
/*https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/ */
display:flex;
-webkit-justify-content: space-around;
-ms-flex-pack: distribute;
justify-content: space-around;
}

 button {
position: absolute;
top: 135%;
}
```

Hope helps!

Answer (score 1):

By wrapping your elements with a `div.wrapper` and by removing the fixed position from your elements it should work.

Have a look at this updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nj0mgwdr/4/

The `.wrapper` div css

```
.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Basson      I like how KISS the solution is.